# Why doesn't Rails generate a view file automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, theory

Theory question. Say one runs..

rails generate controller Sessions --no-test-framework

why does RAILS create "app/views/sessions" path/folder but no basic view file, like "new.html.erb"? You need a basic view file to get the request test(s) to pass anyway.

Comment: Hi did my response below answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a view while generating a controller you would have to do this:

```
rails generate controller sessions (the name of the view)
```

So if you were to want a index view for that controller you would run this command:

```
rails generate controller sessions index
```

That will create the index.html.erb and the index action in your sessions controller

The rails generator will create a controller that looks like this:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController 
  def index
  end
end
```